# Combining Excel workbooks, but need the all worksheets, not just the first

Tags: vba, excel

I found this VBA code that works for combining workbooks in a folder, however, I need to modify it so that **all worksheets in each workbook are copy/pasted** and not just the first worksheet of each workbook. As of now, only the first worksheet in each selected workbook is being copied over. Where can I insert code to find data in all worksheets?

Thanks!

```
Sub MergeSelectedWorkbooks()
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
Dim NRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim NFile As Long
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range

' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
FolderPath = "S:\example"

' Set the current directory to the the folder path.
ChDrive FolderPath
ChDir FolderPath

' Open the file dialog box and filter on Excel files, allowing multiple files
' to be selected.
SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
NRow = 1

' Loop through the list of returned file names
For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
    ' Set FileName to be the current workbook file name to open.
    FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)

    ' Open the current workbook.
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FileName)

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
             After:=WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Cells.Range("A1"), _
             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
             SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z" & LastRow)

    ' Set the destination range to start at column A and be the same size as the source range.
    Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow)
    Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
       SourceRange.Columns.Count)

    ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
    DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

    ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
    NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False
Next NFile

' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all data is readable.
SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: You know how to write a `For...Next` loop. Have you tried making one that parameterizes this hard-coded `(1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Opens multiple workbooks (1 by 1), Copies data from all sheets onto one sheet. Make sure you modify the ranges that will work for you (copy range is currently A2 to Z(last row).

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveSheets()


Dim IndvFiles As FileDialog
Dim Currentbook As Workbook
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim CurrentSheets As Integer
Dim BookCount As Integer

'Opens File Dialog to Select Which Files You Want to Consolidate
    Set IndvFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With IndvFiles
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
        .ButtonName = ""
        .Filters.Clear
        .Show
    End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

CurrentSheets = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
BookCount = IndvFiles.SelectedItems.Count
Dim LROW as Long
DIM LROW2 as Long
DIM Import as Range

        For x = 1 To BookCount
            On Error GoTo StopHere:

            Set Currentbook = Workbooks.Open(IndvFiles.SelectedItems(X))

                For i = 1 To Currentbook.Worksheets.Count
                    LROW = thisworkbook.sheets("desired sheet name paste").Range("A2").End(XLdown).Rows
                    LROW2=currentbook.sheets(i).Range("A2").End(XLdown).Rows
                         Set Import = currentbook.sheets(i).Range("A2:Z"&LROW2)
                         Import.Copy
                              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Desired sheet name paste range").Range("A"&LROW).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks _
                Next i
                Currentbook.Close False
        Next x

StopHere:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I am trying to get all data in all sheets in all selected workbooks pasted into one sheet, rather than having one workbook with multiple sheets.

Comment: Above code has been modified. Make sure to re-name the sheet where all of the data will be pasted and modify the ranges if needed (both changes on code of course). 

You may also want to add something to this to un-hide columns/rows and remove any filters if they exist on any given sheet.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error in the line:

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Desired sheet name paste range").Range("A"&LROW).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks _
                Next i`

I am not very experienced with VBA, so thank you in advance.

Comment: Determine the name of the sheet all of your data is being pasted on. On the above line, swap "Desired sheet name paste range" with the actual name of your sheet. The sheet name has to be in quotes.

Comment: @Andrew is the code doing what you need it to? If so, please hit the check box next to answer :) 

If not, let me know what the issue is

Comment: If a sheet name is entered there, an error occurs stating, "Compile error: Expected: named parameter" and the line "Next i" is highlighted.

Comment: Did you replace the sheet name in both places? Needs to be changed twice within the i loop. 

Will test it again, was working on my end earlier :)

Comment: Yes. The moment that the sheet name is changed, a "named parameter" error is prompted and the "Next i" is highlighted.

Comment: When you have Visual Basic editor open, it will show you the sheet names on the left. You may not have a “sheet1”